# Wordpress - category page navigation

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my permalinks structure:

```
domain.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

I have category that called "blog", this url is working fine:

```
domain.com/blog
```

But the second page and third page are not working in the same way, for example, this url is not working:

```
domain.com/blog/page/2
```

but(!) this url working fine:

```
domain.com/category/blog/page/2
```

Why `domain.com/blog` is working and `domain.com/blog/page/2` not?

Thank you!

Comment: because you have `domain.com/%category%/%postname%/`, where `%postname%` it's `/blog/page/2` not only `/page/2` what you want have?

Comment: I dont unterstand, I tried: domain.com/category/blog/page/2
How I fix that?
I want this url will work fine: domain.com/blog/page/2
Thanks!

Comment: ok, you need to write your url in the way `domain.com/%postname%/` or set the penultimate option `sample-post/`

Comment: You are sure to not you Blog also like Slug name? or Tilte name?

Comment: I change my peramlinks structure to post name and now even this url is not working: domain.com/blog
Because that I used /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Maybe you can try to use Category base, and write Blog. And leave %postname%

Comment: But it should work with any category, not just "blog"